# Given names in a matrix form, print them in ordered form in a single column array

Tags: c, matrix

So i finally arrived at memory allocation and pointers so im quite new at this so i apologize in advance if i made some rookie mistakes.

The exercise as i stated in case i wasnt clear says: Given the names in a matrix form print the result in a single column array in ordered alphabetical form.

We read the data from a file and we have to print them into another.

I've only been able to dynamically allocate the memories but i am stuck as to how to order it. At first i thought since it was in a matrix from i could probably just print it in a file in column form and then order it alphabetically but that would mean i had to allocate more memory to other stuff and i thought that this was deffinitely the long way around and difinitely not the optimal way.

This is the file data:

```
4 3 
milano torino venezia 
bari genova taranto 
firenze napoli roma 
bologna cagliari palermo
```

and the result should look like this

```
12
bari 
bologna 
cagliari
firenze
genova
milano
napoli
palermo
roma
taranto
torino
venezia
```

and this is the code so far:

```c
int main() {
  FILE * file;
  FILE * file2;
  file = fopen("file", "r");
  file2 = fopen("file2", "r"); // here i am using "r" so it doesnt keep annoying me every time 
  // i compile the program
  if (file == NULL || file2 == NULL) {
    printf("Error in opening the files!!!");
    exit(1);
  }
  int n, m;
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  fscanf(file, "%d %d", & n, & m);
  char name[N + 1];
  char ** * v;
  v = (char ** * ) malloc(n * sizeof(char ** ));
  if (v == NULL) {
    printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    v[i] = (char ** ) malloc(m * sizeof(char * ));
    if (v[i] == NULL) {
      printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      fscanf(file, "%s", name);
      v[i][j] = strdup(name);
      if (v[i][j] == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: regarding: `char ** * v;`  you might want to read: [three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: regarding: `char name[N + 1];`  the variable 'N' is not defined

Comment: regarding: ` printf("Memory allocation error.\n");`  This does tell the user that some problem happened, but not the 'why'  Suggest using something similar to: `perror( "malloc failed" );` as that will output your error message AND the reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: regarding: `file2 = fopen("file2", "r");`  the file descriptor: `file2` is not used in the posted code.  (and per your comment in the code, the compiler is saying the same thing.  Suggest removing that line

Comment: 2 space indents can/will be lost when using variable width fonts.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces